# Getting the device ID/Handle of a mouse with Raw Input

Tags: c#, windows, mouseevent, raw-input

I'm working on using the raw input api to listen for key presses and mouse clicks. So far I have the keyboard presses working, I'm able to get events to fire for such and read which key was pressed. However, I'm having trouble getting the mouse events to work the same way.

When the message comes in via
`WndProc(ref Message)`, there's a device handle that doesn't ever match anything from the list of device IDs (keyboards, mice, and HIDs). Moreover, the raw input buffer is empty with all fields being zero.

Does anyone have suggestions on how/why this would happen?

Note, I've been trying to use:
`private static extern uint GetRawInputDeviceInfo(IntPtr hDevice, uint command, ref DeviceInfo data, ref uint dataSize);` to get any data about the click event's source device, but again the data is also empty/zero.

Thanks

Edit:

On startup I get a list of all devices seen by raw input:

```
var pRawInputDeviceList = Marshal.AllocHGlobal((int)(dwSize * deviceCount));
GetRawInputDeviceList(pRawInputDeviceList, ref deviceCount, (uint)dwSize);
```

Once I have this list of devices I iterate through them and add them to a separate `dictionary<deviceID, eventType>`.

Later, once I receive a message through `WndProc(ref Message)`, I grab the identifier under `message.LParam`, but this doesn't match any device ID in my original list.

Comment: Presumably you're calling either `GetRawInputData` or `GetRawInputBuffer`. Most likely there's an issue with how the `RAWINPUT` struct is marshaled if you're using the first, and if you're using the second, you may not be allocating the memory correctly. Also what comparison are you doing when you say `there's a device handle that doesn't ever match anything from the list of device IDs`?

Comment: @theB I added an edit that I hope explains a bit better in answer to your question. I'm using GetRawInputData(), I can look at the marshal bit and see if anything appears off

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After debugging further I've found that debugging raw input in Visual Studio is tricky at best.

That said, my conclusion that is if you're trying to step through raw input code that's handling key events and mouse clicks, be careful that you're actually following the same thread for each step. In my case, I would receive a mouse event and hit a break point. Using F10/F11 to step through caused inconsistencies when moving between classes. (the mouse event was suddenly a key event and so on)

Therefore, I found using the UI commands in Visual Studio to step over and into to work better as opposed to introducing key events into the flow.